# PHP - Adventofcode - Day 1

Tags: php

```
<?php

// From adventofcode.com

// Question 1:
// An opening parenthesis, (, means he should go up one floor, and a closing parenthesis,
// ), means he should go down one floor.
// To what floor do the instructions take Santa?

// Question 2:
// Now, given the same instructions, find the position of the first character that causes him to enter the basement
// (floor -1). The first character in the instructions has position 1, the second character has position 2, and so on.
// For example:
// ) causes him to enter the basement at character position 1.
// ()()) causes him to enter the basement at character position 5.
// What is the position of the character that causes Santa to first enter the basement?

$puzzle = '()(((()))(()()()((((()(((())(()(()((((((()(()(((())))((()(((()))((())(()((()()()()(((())(((((((())))()()(()(()(())(((((()()()((())(((((()()))))()(())(((())(())((((((())())))(()())))()))))()())()())((()()((()()()()(()((((((((()()())((()()(((((()(((())((())(()))()((((()((((((((())()((()())(())((()))())((((()())(((((((((((()()(((((()(()))())(((()(()))())((()(()())())())(()(((())(())())()()(()(()((()))((()))))((((()(((()))))((((()(()(()())())()(((()((((())((((()(((()()(())()()()())((()((((((()((()()))()((()))()(()()((())))(((()(((()))((()((()(()))(((()()(()(()()()))))()()(((()(((())())))))((()(((())()(()(())((()())))((((())))(()(()(()())()((()())))(((()((()(())()()((()((())(()()((())(())()))()))((()(())()))())(((((((()(()()(()(())())))))))(()((((((())((((())((())())(()()))))()(())(()())()())((())(()))))(()))(()((()))()(()((((((()()()()((((((((()(()(())((()()(()()))(())()())()((())))()))()())(((()))(())()(())()))()((()((()(()()())(())()()()((())())))((()()(()()((()(())()()())(((()(()()))))(())))(()(()())()))()()))))))()))))((((((())))())))(()(())())(()())))))(()))()))))))()((()))))()))))(()(()((()())())(()()))))(((())()))())())())(((()(()()))(())()(())(())((((((()()))))((()(()))))))(()))())(((()()(()))()())()()()())))))))))))))(())(()))(()))((()(())(()())(())())(()())(())()()(()())))()()()))(())())()))())())(())((())))))))(())))(())))))()))))((())(()(((()))))(()))()((()(())))(()())(((((()))()())()()))))()))))()))())(()(()()()))()))))))((()))))))))))()((()))((()(())((())()()(()()))()(()))))()()(()))()))(((())))(())()((())(())(()())()())())))))))())))()((())))()))(()))()()))(((((((()))())(()()))(()()(()))()(()((()())()))))))(((()()()())))(())()))()())(()()))()()))))))))(())))()))()()))))))()))()())))()(())(())))))()(())()()(()()))))())((()))))()))))(()(((((()))))))))())))())()(())()()))))(())))())()()())()()())()(()))))()))()))))))))())))((()))()))()))())))()())()()())))())))(()((())()((()))())))))())()(())((())))))))))))())()())(())())())(()))(()))()))())(()(())())()())()()(()))))(()(())))))))(())))())(())))))))())()()(())())())))(())))))()))()(()())()(()))())())))))()()(()))()))))())))))))))()))))()))))))())()())()()))))()())))())))))))))))()()))))()()(((()))()()(())()))))((()))))(()))(())())))(())()))))))(()))()))))(())())))))()))(()())))))))))))))())))))))))()((()())(()())))))))((()))))(())(())))()(()())())))())())(()()()())))()))))))())))))())()()())))))))))))()()(()))))()())()))((()())(()))))()(()))))))))))()())())(((())(()))))())()))()))()))))))()))))))(()))))()))))()(())))(())))(()))())()()(()()))()))(()()))))))))()))(()))())(()()(()(()())()()))()))))))))(())))))((()()(()))())())))))()))())(()())()()))())))()(()()()()))((())())))())()(()()))()))))))))(()))(())))()))))(()(()())(()))))()())())()))()()))())))))))))))())()))))))()))))))))())))))()))))())(()())))(())()))())())))))()()(()()())(()())))()()))(((()))(()()()))))()))))()))))((())))()((((((()()))))))())))))))))))(((()))))))))))))(())())))))())(()))))))(()))((()))())))()(()((()))()))()))))))))))())()))()(()()))))())))())(())()(()))()))())(()))()))))(()()))()()(())))))()))(())(()(()()))(()()())))))(((()))))))()))))))))))))(())(()))))()())())()()((()()))())))))(()))))())))))))()()()))))))))())))()(((()()))(())))))(((())())))))((()))()(()))(()))))(()())))(()))())))))()))))(())(())))()((()))(())())))()()))()))))))))()))(()()()(()()()(()))())(())()())(((()))(())))))))))(((()())))()()))))))))()(())(()))()((((())(())(()())))()))(((())()()()))((()))(()))())())))())))(()))())()())())(()(())())()()()(())))())(())))(())))(())()))()))(()((()))))))))())(()))))))())(()()))()()))()(()(()())))()()(()((()((((((()))(())))()()()))())()))((()()(()))())((()(()(()))(()()))))()())))()))()())))))))()()((()())(())))()))(()))(())(()))())(()(())))()()))))))(((()(((()()))()(()(())())((()()))()))()))()))()(()()()(()))((()())()(())))()()))(((())()()())(())()((()()()()(()(())(()()))()(((((()())))((())))))(()()()))))(((()(())))()))((()((()(())()(()((())))((()())()(()))(((()())()()(()))(())(((()((()())()((())()())(((()()))((()((())(()))(()())(()()()))((()))(())(()((()()())((()))(())))(())(())(())))(()())))(((((()(()(((((()())((((()(()())(())(()()(((())((()(((()()(((()()((((((())))())(()((((((()(()))()))()()((()((()))))()(()()(()((()()))))))(((((()(((((())()()()(())())))))))()))((()()(())))(())(()()()())))))(()((((())))))))()()(((()(()(()(()(()())()()()(((((((((()()())()(()))((()()()()()(((((((()())()((())()))((((((()(()(()(()())(((()(((((((()(((())(((((((((())(())())()))((()(()))(((()()())(())(()(()()(((()(())()))())))(())((((((())(()()())()()(((()(((())(()(((())(((((((()(((((((((()))(())(()(()(()))))((()))()(())())())((()(()((()()))((()()((()(())(())(()((())(((())(((()()()((((((()()(())((((())()))))(())((()(()((())))(((((()(()()())())((())())))((())((()((()()((((((())(((()()(()())())(()(()))(()(()))())())()(((((((()(((()(())()()((())((()(()()((()(()()(((((((((((())((())((((((())((()((((()(()((((()(((((((())()((()))))())()((()((((()(()(((()((()())))(())())(((()(((())((((((()(((((((((()()(())))(()(((((()((((()())))((()((()((()(()()(((())((((((((((((()(((())(()(((((()))(()()(()()()()()()((())(((((((())(((((())))))())()(()()(()(()(((()()(((((())(()((()((()(((()()((()((((())()))()((((())(())))()())(((())(())(()()((()(((()()((((((((((()()(()())())(((((((((())((((()))()()((((())(()((((()(((())())(((((((((((()((((())))(())(()(((()(((()((())(((((()((()()(()(()()((((((()((((()((()(()((()(()((((((()))))()()(((((()((()(()(())()))(())(((((((()((((()())(()((()((()(()))())))(())((()))))(((((((()()()())(()))(()()((()())()((()((()()()(()(()()))(()())(())(((((()(((((((((((()((()(((()(((((((()()((((((()(((((()(()((()(((((())((((((()))((((())((()()((())(((())()(((((()()(((((()((()(()(((((((()(((((()((()((()((())(())((())(()))()()))(()()(()(()()(((((((()(((()(((())()(((((()((((((()())((((())()((()((()(()()())(()))((((()()((((((()((()(()(()((((()((()((())((((((()(()(())((((((()((((((((((()((())()))()(()(()(((((()()()))((())))()(()((((((((((((((()(((()((((()((())((()((()(((()()(()(((()((())(()()())))()(()(()(((((()()(()(()((((()(((((())()(()(()))(((((()()(((()()(())((((((((((((((())((())(((((((((((())()()()(())()(()(()(((((((((())(((()))(()()())(()((((()(())(((((()())(())((((((((())()((((()((((((())(()((()(())(((()((((()))(((((((((()()))((((()(())()()()(())(()((())((()()))()(((())(((((())((((((()()))(((((((((()((((((())))(((((((()((()(()(())))())(()(()))()(((((()())(()))()(()(())(((()))))())()())))(((((()))())()((()(()))))((()()()((((((()))()()((((((((())((()(()(((()(()((())((()())(()((((())(()(((()()()(()(()()))())())((((((((((())())((()))()((())(())(())))())()(()()(())))())(()))(((()(()()(((()(((())))()(((()(())()((((((())()))()))()((((((()(()(((((()())))()))))())()()(((()(((((())((()()(()((()((()(()(()(())))(()()()()((()(())(((()((()))((((()))())(())))())(()))()()()())()))(((()()())()((())))(())(()()()()(()())((()(()()((((())))((()((()(())((()(()((())()(()()(((()())()()())((()))((())(((()()(())))()()))(((()((())()(((((()())(())((())()())())((((((()(()(((((()))(()(';

$nbItems = strlen($puzzle);

$floor = 0;
$foundPosition = false;

for ($i=0; $i < $nbItems; $i++)
{
  $char = $puzzle[$i];

  if ($floor === -1 && $foundPosition === false)
  {
    $foundPosition = $i;
  }

  if ($char === '(')
  {
    $floor++;
  }
  else
  {
    $floor--;
  }
}

print $floor . PHP_EOL;
print $foundPosition . PHP_EOL;

?>
```

The code is correct and returns:

```
138
1771
```

I'm looking for the most elegant way / the best time complexity to tackle the problem ;)

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! This question is incomplete. To help reviewers give you better answers, please add sufficient context to your question. The more you tell us about what your code does and what the purpose of doing that is, the easier it will be for reviewers to help you. See also [this meta question](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1226/code-should-include-a-description-of-what-the-code-does).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### To what floor do the instructions take Santa?

There is no need to go character by character to determine that, instead:

```
$puzzle = '...';

$up = substr_count($puzzle, '(');
$down = substr_count($puzzle, ')');
$floor = $up - $down;
// $floor = 138
```

### The position that causes him to enter the basement

This can be significantly simplified e.g.:

```
$puzzle = '...';

$position = 0;
$floor = 0;
while ($floor !== -1) {
    $char = $puzzle[$position];
    ($char === '(') ? $floor++ : $floor--;
    $position++;
}
// $position = 1771
```

Note that there's no need to continue to the end once the answer has been obtained - this alone make determining the answer faster.

This doesn't defend against out-of-bound problems, but it also doesn't need to.

Comment: Sounds smart to me for the logic behind the first question. But I'm positive substr_count() is taking more memory than the loop.

Comment: positive -> benchmark it ;). I haven't since you didn't mention memory, only elegance, at the time of writing an answer; generally speaking, a builtin function is going to be a better solution than doing something yourself.